# Missing sequence or table: hibernate_sequence and I don't need it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using hibernate 4.2.7, Oracle 12c and sequences for each table and still my application asks me this sequence.

Each table uses its own sequence as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "foo_seq", sequenceName = "foo_seq", initialValue = 1)
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "foo_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    ...
}
```

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
@EnableJpaAuditing
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class, excludeFilters = @Filter({Controller.class}))
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:foo.properties"})
public class Application {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            ((BasicDataSource) dataSource).setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
            ((BasicDataSource) dataSource).setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            ((BasicDataSource) dataSource).setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            ((BasicDataSource) dataSource).setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.TRUE);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(Application.class.getPackage().getName() + ".domain");
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"););
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        return factory;
    }

    ...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing sequence or
>   table: hibernate_sequence     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1316)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:509)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1794)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
>   [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]     ... 107 more

I use jboss 6.2. Why this sequence asks me if I do not use anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

I found my problem. I have a custom class which extends AbstractPersistable.

Comment: I could not understand your answer. The problem was because you have custom class which `extends AbstractPersisttable` or it was a solution to your problem?